# Ubuntu 20 Or Lubuntu 20 doesn't suspend on Toshiba Chromebook

Tags: lubuntu, 20.04, suspend, chromebook

Ubuntu doesn't suspend on toshiba chromebook. everything works cool in new  20 release exept of course sound which never worked after 14 and suspend which worked until 19 but now the power just cuts off. Is there any chance to alter? or may be use older kernel? thanks in advance